# Complex number quadratic with conjugation

Tags: complex-numbers, quadratics

I have the following equation:
$$
3z^2+z^*-1=0
$$
z is a complex number and $z^*$ is its conjugate. I'm stuck solving it. There's what I did so far:
$$
z = a+bi
$$
$$
3a^2+6abi-3b^2+a+bi=1
$$
Assuming $Im(z) = 0$ I'm getting following equations:
$$
\begin{cases}
3a^2-3b^2+a=1\\
6abi-bi=0
\end{cases}
$$
$$
bi(6a-1)=0=>b=0 \lor a=-\frac{1}{6}
$$

Since $b=0$, I'm getting
$$
3a^2+a=1
$$
which will have 2 solutions. I have no idea what should I do next since I will be getting 3 different $a$'s, but wolfram shows me only 2 solutions.
$$
z = -\frac{1}{6} - \frac{\sqrt{13}}{6}
$$
$$
z = \frac{\sqrt{13}}{6} -\frac{1}{6}
$$

Comment: "I have no idea what should I do next since I will be getting 3 diffrent a's, but wolfram shows me only 2 solutions": do it anyways and see if you *actually* end up with three solutions. Right now you are just staying still midway into the solution speculating that it might not work.

Comment: $3a^2+6abi-3b^2+a-bi=1.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a=-\dfrac16$, then $3a^2-3b^2+a=\dfrac1{12}-3b^2-\dfrac16=1\iff 3b^2=\dfrac1{12}-\dfrac16-1$,

which has no real solutions for $b$, so there really are only the two solutions from when $b=0$.

Comment: I did exactly this just as @Gae.S.suggested and it's indeed the proof I needed. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 2):

The given equation implies

$$ z=1-3(z^*)^2=1-3(1-3z^2)^2=-2+18z^2-27z^4
$$
which factorizes as
$$(3z^2+z-1)(3z+1)(3z-2)=0$$
and yields the solutions $z=-\frac16\pm \frac{\sqrt{13}}6$, while $z=\frac23,-\frac13$ are invalid.

Comment: (+1) Always like "pure" complex number solution.

Answer (score 0):

Well, we are trying to solve:

$$3\text{z}^2+\overline{\text{z}}-1=0\tag1$$

As you did, let's set $\text{z}:=\alpha+\beta i$ where $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\beta\in\mathbb{R}$. So we get:

$$3\left(\alpha+\beta i\right)^2+\alpha-\beta i-1=0\tag2$$

Expanding $\left(\alpha+\beta i\right)^2$, gives:

$$\left(\alpha+\beta i\right)^2=\alpha^2-\beta^2+2\alpha\beta i\tag3$$

So, we get:

$$3\left(\alpha^2-\beta^2+2\alpha\beta i\right)+\alpha-\beta i-1=0\tag4$$

Finding the real and imaginary parts, we can set:

$$
\begin{cases}
\Re\left(3\left(\alpha^2-\beta^2+2\alpha\beta i\right)+\alpha-\beta i-1\right)=0\\
\\
\Im\left(3\left(\alpha^2-\beta^2+2\alpha\beta i\right)+\alpha-\beta i-1\right)=0
\end{cases}\tag5
$$

This gives:

$$
\begin{cases}
3\alpha^2-3\beta^2+\alpha-1=0\\
\\
6\alpha\beta-\beta=0
\end{cases}\tag6
$$

Solving the second equation for $\beta$ gives:

$$\beta=0\tag7$$

So:

$$3\alpha^2-3\cdot0^2+\alpha-1=0\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\alpha=\frac{\pm\sqrt{13}-1}{6}\tag8$$

> As pointed out by [@Gae. S.](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/239203/gae-s), try to prove or disprove that $\alpha=\frac{1}{6}$ is or isn't a solution to your problem.

Comment: @Gae.S. Good observation, I edited my answer.